# How to make input in HTML for Telerik

Tags: forms, input, telerik

I am doing export to PDF from HTML. I want to add input fields into my HTML code, but I don't know how.

I have tried a lot of combinations, but nothing is working.

Here is example what I tried:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKgbZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadClientExportManager to export HTML content and elements to PDF. For example, see this demo - https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/client-export-manager/functionality/export-html-elements/defaultcs.aspx.
Another approach to export HTML to PDF is to use the [Kendo Drawing API](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/pdf/overview#drawing-library).

Comment: Thank you for your response Rumen. I know there are other options, but I have to do it my way. I have to write HTML template, which will generate PDF template.

Comment: Then you can check the Page Templates - https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/pdf-output/page-templates.